# Want to change a JButton with half red and half blue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcomponent

I want to set my JButton background color with half red and half blue. Can I do that in java swing without using graphics 2D? Please help me!

Comment: Please explain more -- half red text? background-color? something else? What have you researched? What have you tried? Please go through the [ask].

Comment: “Can I do that in java swing without using graphics 2D?”  In a word: no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by making it gradient.

```
   buttonGraphics.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
                        new Point(0, 0), 
                        Color.RED, 
                        new Point(0, getWidth()), 
                        Color.BLUE()));
                buttonGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                buttonGraphics.dispose()
```

Comment: If you want it vertically gradient, use getHeight() instead of getWidth().

Comment: Thanks Collins . Am sorry that my question was incomplete. Actually i want to change the background color of the button . Can i do it without using Graphics 2D.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels wow, thanks, my mind was seeing things.